# Adding dynamic controls to winform not working

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am creating dynamic `PictureBox` and label in `WinForms`. For this I have created a method which creates these items on the basis of given integer. In the first run while loading the form, its works smoothly, but when  I pass any integer from a dropdown box, it does not make any changes. I tried debugging the code, and all the labels are created accordingly but it is not reflected in the `winForm`. I tried using Invalidate, Update, Refresh but non of them worked.

Here is the method that I have implemented.

```
private void createPictureBox(int size)
{
    //this.Controls.Clear();
    panel1.Controls.Clear();
    Label[] ParameterLabel = new Label[size];
    PictureBox[] ParameterBack = new PictureBox[size];
    int y_value = 11;
    this.Refresh();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {

        ParameterLabel[i] = new Label();
        ParameterLabel[i].Text = "Test Text";
        ParameterLabel[i].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 8, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(128)));
        ParameterLabel[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        ParameterLabel[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(1, 0, 64);
        ParameterLabel[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(145, 20);
        ParameterLabel[i].Location = new Point(30, y_value);
        ParameterLabel[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
        ParameterLabel[i].Visible = true;

        ParameterBack[i] = new PictureBox();
        ParameterBack[i].Image = Image.FromFile(STR_SETTING_PATH + "\\" + STR_IDEA_NO_XXXXX + "_01_nv.png");
        ParameterBack[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 32);
        ParameterBack[i].Location = new Point(2, y_value - 10);
        ParameterBack[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
        ParameterBack[i].Visible = true;
        //this.Controls.Add(ParameterBack[i]);

        y_value += 37;
    }
    panel1.Controls.AddRange(ParameterLabel);
    panel1.Controls.AddRange(ParameterBack);
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: This is probably because your y_value is declared inside the method, making each call of this method to place the elements it creates on top of elements it created the last time.

Comment: Yes I want to create the controls from the beginning like a new one.

Comment: The problme is that you re always adding controls - how do you plan to get rid of some? you are piling PictureBox'es on top of each other. Where do you  remove the old ones?

Answer (score 1):

Who can you distinguish between controls created in the first call and those created in other calls? I've tested your function with a tiny change, it seems to be working fine:

```
int CallIndex = 0; // this is on the form level

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createPictureBox(3);
        CallIndex += 1;
    }

    private void createPictureBox(int size)
    {
    // this has the exact same code as your method (copy-paste into my visual studio), 
    // except this change: 
    // ParameterLabel[i].Text = "Test Text";
    ParameterLabel[i].Text = string.Format("Test {0}", CallIndex); // instead of the row above
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did remove the previously added controls and added the new one after which apparently solved my problem. The problem was due to piling of Controls one over another. I first removed the previously created controls using

```
this.Controls.Remove(UserControl1);
```

Then re-created its instance, which solved my problem.